# A smarter way to add multiple event listeners?

Tags: javascript

To start using the javascript skills i've been learning i created a page where you click the numbers from 1-5 and they slowly disappear. Is there a better way to code rather than listing the event listeners inside each other?

```
 const one = document.querySelector(".one");
const two = document.querySelector(".two");
const three = document.querySelector(".three");
const four = document.querySelector(".four");
const five = document.querySelector(".five");

one.addEventListener('click', e => {
one.remove();
two.addEventListener('click', e => {
  two.remove();
  three.addEventListener('click', e => {
    three.remove();
    four.addEventListener('click', e => {
      four.remove();
      five.addEventListener('click', e => {
        five.remove();
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

[image: Webpage image]

Comment: Are you wanting to force the users to click them in order?  If so, nesting them like this is one strategy

Answer (score 0):

Make the listeners peers and add a little data to keep state of which one must be clicked next...

```
let listenTo = 1

one.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (listenTo === 1) {
    listenTo = 2
    // fade away code
  }
})

two.addEventListener ...
```

These could be setup in one loop, also, like this...

```
// give the elements id="zero", etc in the markup
let ids = [ "zero", "one", "two" ... ]
let listenTo = "zero"

let listeners = ids.map((id, index) => {
  let el = document.getElementById(id)
  return el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (listenTo === id) {
      listenTo = index < ids.length-1 ? ids[index+1] : null
      // fade away code
    }
  })
})
```